# Can't perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am trying to restore a transaction log to the database with a Python script. But I get an error message

> cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction

How can I solve this problem?

```
query_ms=r"""
RESTORE LOG [miadmfggp_live] FROM
DISK =N'C:\yardi_backup\extract\201811081130.bak0',
WITH  STANDBY =N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.YARDI_BACKUP_DEV\MSSQL\Backup\standby_log_file.bak' ;
"""
cursor_ms.execute(query_ms)
result=cursor_ms.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cursor_ms.autocommit='true' could solve the problem

Comment: This *does* solve the problem (for pymssql anyway - REF: https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html?highlight=autocommit#basic-features-strict-db-api-compliance